# ssh from docker container

Tags: docker, ssh

i'm able to ssh from host computer "H" into a remote computer "R", but not from within a docker container "D" (which is on the host computer "H") into the remote computer "R".

I'm getting the below error on the docker terminal:

`Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: no matching key exchange method found.`

I accessed the docker container terminal using: `docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash`

Please let me know if i missed anything.

Comment: It doesn't belong to docker problems, you should consider search for ssh instead https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402746/ssh-unable-to-negotiate-no-matching-key-exchange-method-found

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your docker container session does include a ~/id_rsa key whose public key has been added to the remote user .ssh/.authorized_keys, you might need to authorize the requested cypher offered by the remote server.

See for example "[How to enable diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 key exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/340844/7490) "

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 ...
```

Or "[ssh unable to negotiate - no matching key exchange method found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402792/7490)"